# Best way to compact a string in PHP that can be decoded to its original form

Tags: php

What would be the best way to compact a string in PHP that can be decoded to its original form. The base64_encode works for numbers but it yields a longer result for strings that contain special characters.

Comment: The result of `base64_encode` is about 133% the size of the original string. It's not a compression algorithm.

Comment: Its not always 133% of the original. For numbers, base64_encode gives a string shorter than the original.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Messing around with [an online base64 encoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp), I couldn't find a number pattern that wasn't directed by the 133% ratio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Gzencode`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php) and [`gzdecode`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) use the GZIP compression algorithm and are very efficient on plain text strings. Just be aware that the output may (will) contain binary characters not suitable for display and possibly not suitable for database storage either.

(Edit: singe `gzdecode` doesn't ship with PHP, consider [`gzdeflate`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php) and [`gzinflate`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php). `Gzdeflate` compresses a string and `gzinflate` decompresses it.)

Comment: I had tried those but in my case, I need the result to be ascii, URL friendly characters.

Comment: @Rajv, gzencode is probably efficient enough that base64_encode won't completely cancel it out.

Comment: 2 years after and `gzdecode` is still not shipped with PHP. Better stick with `gzcompress`.

Answer (score 0):

Take your pick: [Compression and Archive Extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php)

Answer (score 0):

well of course a base64-encoding makes a string longer as it is mapping all possible bytes onto a smaller set of numbers and alphabetic chars.

I guess [convert_uuencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uuencode.php) wouldn't increase the size of your binary string as much as base64 b/c the target set is larger.