# Compacting string data for storage and retrieval

Tags: php, mysql

I have some text data I would like to store in a mysql database. I currently have the data stored in a variable as a string.

I'm concerned that the table will become quite large due to the amount of text data I have for each row.

Therefore, what is the most easiest way (preferably php built in functions) of compacting this string data in a format ideal for storage and retrieval?

Comment: What data type is the column that you are you storing the data in?

Comment: Perhaps the answer on another topic may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733659/best-way-to-compact-a-string-in-php-that-can-be-decoded-to-its-original-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could GZIP the string with [GZEncode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php).

That's pretty standard and thus should be reversible from other languages if you want to.

I would advise storing a Base64 version of the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using InnoDB you can enable compression on entire tables which doesn't impact your code at all.

```
ALTER TABLE database.tableName ENGINE='InnoDB' ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8;
```

You can alter the KEY_BLOCK_SIZE to smaller values to get more compression (depending on the data), but this adds more overhead to the CPU.
After testing a range of tables, I found a KEY_BLOCK_SIZE of 8 to be a good balance of compression vs performance.